# Где работает HSTS, на клиентской стороне или на серверной?

Tags: веб-программирование

Имеется dev сайт где разрабы тестят фронтю
буквально вчера появилась ошибка при заходе на сайт, которой работае только на http, 50 процентов машин принудительно кидает на https причем с абсолютно разных браузеров.я хочу определить где эта проблема на стороне сервера или клиентов. и где же все таки работает HSTS? на клиентской стороне или на серверной

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете домены `.dev` для работы, то проблема именно в них. В последних версиях Chrome этот домен [был включён его владельцем в HSTS Preload List](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/). Это значит что на этот домен и его поддомены можно зайти только по https. Забудьте про `.dev` и никогда не используйте его поддомены. Если, конечно, вы не работаете в Google.

Используйте какой-нибудь другой зарезервированный поддомен вроде `.localhost` или `.test` и всё у вас будет хорошо.

Если же дело не в `.dev`, то дело было так:

1. Сначала была ошибка конфигурации сервера или приложения, которая заключалась в выдаче заголовков HSTS. Пока браузеры не увидели этот заголовок, они и не думали никого переадресовывать на https.
2. Потом, даже после исправления ошибки на сервере, все браузеры видевшие такой заголовок однажды продолжают заходить на сайты по https и будут продолжать пока не истечёт время, указанное в заголовке. Или пока вы не сбросите настройки HSTS в браузере. В Chrome это делается заходом на **chrome://net-internals/#hsts** и поиском вашего домена для удаления его из списка.

Таким образом можно сказать что HSTS работает и со стороны сервера, и со стороны клиента. Просто часть работы у каждого своя.

Comment: `.localhost` тоже нельзя, потому что некоторые браузеры принудительно присваивают всем поддоменам 127.0.0.1 независимо от содержимого файла hosts (причём правильно делают)

Comment: Почему нельзя? Если для локальной разработки, то это именно то, что нужно. И не нужно `hosts` переписывать каждый раз.

Comment: Даже для локальной нельзя, потому что даже из виртуалки на `.localhost` уже не зайти, потому что у виртуалки своя сеть и свой локалхост)

Comment: дев у нас крутится на амазоне и на домене первого уровня)

Comment: Тогда вторая часть ответа - про вас